# How do I download multiple files one after another?

Tags: powershell, download, command-prompt, idm

I have two questions.
I use " curl " for downloading files via Command prompt. if there is any other way, please tell me.

The first one is, how I can download multiple files one after another with PowerShell or cmd with one character difference.

```
like part-1.mp4 up to part-150.mp4

C:\Users\Omar\Downloads\Video\Complete CCNA from Associate to CCNA Expert>curl -O http://cdn3.amoozesh.af/drive1/Amoozesh/CCNA-2016-Complete/Part-1.mp4 "How i can add multiple downloads one after another part-150.mp4
```

The second one is, how I can download the Folder itself without going to download file by file as shown in I photo and command.

```
C:\Users\Omar\Downloads\Video\Complete CCNA from Associate to CCNA Expert>curl -O http://cdn3.amoozesh.af/drive1/Amoozesh/CCNA-2016-Complete <<< in here the folder is shown. is it possible to download a folder via the same URL?
```

[image]

Comment: Command-prompt has a `For` loop where you can run a command as a loop. For help its `For /?` looking online for more specific examples. Eg: `FOR /L %a IN (1,1,150) DO Echo "curl -O https://website.com/part-%a.mp3"`

In PowerShell `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` so you'd need to work on a loop in PowerShell doing `curl` or `Invoke-WebRequest` Eg: `1..150 | ForEach-Object { "Invoke-WebRequest -uri https://website.com/part-$Psitem.mp3" }`

Comment: @user4317867 You should make this an actual answer.

Comment: Can you have a look at this? I entered the command as you told me. it says cannot resolve ""Invoke-WebRequest 1..3 | ForEach-Object {"Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://cdn3.amoozesh.af/drive1/Amoozesh/CCNA-2016-Complete/Part-$psitem.mp4"}

Comment: And it says Invalid URI: the host name could not be parsed.
is it possible that you just write the exact command in PowerShell or command prompt

Comment: The command prompt script is just, Printing the script itself, as many times regarding condition.

Comment: ohhhh, man My fault, sorry for that.!!!!!!!
It worked just doing "echo for no reasone"

Comment: And sorry for this much causeing headache,! how can I access the folder that is shared or via that URL, is there any way to just download the folder without going through all these downloading files.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comment to an Answer:

(Editing to mention Stack Overflow can help with answering a question or two, ultimately you'll learn better by researching answers on your own but asking on here when you run into some trouble)

The Command-prompt has a `For loop` where you can run a command as a loop.

For help its: `For /?`  and check online for more specific examples.

Eg: `FOR /L %a IN (1,1,150) DO Echo "curl -O https://website.com/part-%a.mp3"`

Keeping in mind that the above `For loop` only writes the text to the screen as a way of ensuring the command looks correct, when you get the output looking correct, remove the `ECHO` and make the command `FOR /L %a IN (1,1,150) DO curl -O https://website.com/part-%a.mp3`

In PowerShell `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` so you'd need to work on a loop in PowerShell doing curl or Invoke-WebRequest.

Eg: `1..150 | ForEach-Object { "Invoke-WebRequest -uri https://website.com/part-$Psitem.mp3" }`

Keep in mind the Powershell example only writes a string to the console, when you have the output looking correct you can make the actual command:

```
1..150 | ForEach-Object {

Invoke-WebRequest -uri https://website.com/part-$Psitem.mp3"

}
```